# Anchor link not firing

Tags: html, css

Can anyone understand why the anchor link in my carousel isnt working - i'm pulling my hair out with this one!

the pink links in the carousel are selectable - show up as a link destination - but nothing happens on click!?

I have tried altering the url with Firebug - it wont fire to anything - yet it works fine if I take the link out of the OL!?  Very frustrating..  any help greatly appreciated..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By looking at the source of your page, I noticed you are using bootstrap carousel.

The reason why the link inside the white box is not working is because you have `data-target="#myCarousel"` in it. By removing this via developer tools, I was able to click on the links.

```
<!-- Original snippet -->
<li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active">
  <div class="carousel-text">
    <h2>A REBRAND AND REPOSITION FOR J.B. LEITCH SOLICITORS </h2>
    <a class="crLnk" href="jb-leitch">Find Out More</a>
    <div class="car_count"><span>1</span> / 3</div>
  </div>
</li>

<!-- Updated snippet -->
<li data-slide-to="0" class="active">
  <div class="carousel-text">
    <h2>A REBRAND AND REPOSITION FOR J.B. LEITCH SOLICITORS </h2>
    <a class="crLnk" href="jb-leitch">Find Out More</a>
    <div class="car_count"><span>1</span> / 3</div>
  </div>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is prevented by javascript code in bootstrap js. you need to find and comment it out.

this is just assumption.

```
$(".crLnk").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

you need to check bootstrap carousel javascript code.

Comment: I cannot understand what your first statement is trying to say. I'd request you to please improve it.